# Can't we use .NET WCF service to upload a PDF file and View it on a browser using Google Docs Service Account

Tags: google-drive-api

There is a requirement in our project where a WCF service Generates a PDF file and stores on the server. And this file needs to be viewed on the browser.

The solution I got is To upload the PDF file on to the GOOgle Drive. Then view it on the browser.

My question is Using WCF service There is no user interaction for Authentication. So it is a Two legged process.

Could anybody give me a sample code to Upload a File onto Google Docs using Service Account using C#.NET in WCF if possible.

Comment: there is documentation for this. try it and let us know whats not working.

Comment: I searched documentation, But I found sample code for JAVA, PHP but I didn't find one for C#.NET. At this point I just need to know, is this possible in WCF?? Then I will do my research to on it. Could you please confirm me if you know about this..

Comment: just googled "google drive api c#" and the first result is the official google docs about it. why not that?

Comment: Yeah I see that and that is a general way of Authentication. But my case is with Service Accounts. Where there is no User Interaction for Authentication. I didn't found .NET example in the Documentation.